# create bootable sdcard for embedded board which will ultimately run android

Tags: android, linux-kernel, sd-card, u-boot

Context:

I designed an embedded system and I ported Android Gingerbread to run on it. I use an ARM Cortex-A8 based CPU module that has the CPU, SDRAM, NANDFLASH on it and all the rest available on module pins so I can add my own hardware interfaces. The first one came with u-boot pre-installed. All I had to do to install my Gingerbread was to place the 4 images (kernel.img, system.img, ramdisk-yaffs.img and userdata.img) in a directory (/sdfuse) on the SD-CARD and just burn it to the on-board NANDFLASH using command "sdfuse flash kernel kernel.img" and the equivalent commands for the other 3 files. Simple enough. After that, I use the SDCARD in Android as an external storage. (Life was good!)

The Problem:

Now I bought more modules and they did not come with u-boot pre-loaded. So, I need to make a bootable SDcard with u-boot on it. It needs to be FAT in order to be recognized by my processor at boot time. I actually have a SDHC 4GB card in FAT32, successfully installed U-boot and it boots my system up to the u-boot prompt telling me it can't find the 4 image files. It's expected since the images are not there yet. The problem is now I can't create the /sdfuse folder and put the 4 image files on it. Neither my MACBook nor my Ubuntu machine let me mount that SDcard anymore to create the "/sdfuse" folder on it. Both diskmanagers see the SD-Card but neither allow to mount it. Obviously, I missed something somewhere. What I have now is a bootable 4GB FAT32 SD-Card with U-boot on it but the rest of the card is not usable anymore. Anybody knows what the problem could be? Why can't I use this 4GB bootable FAT32 partition to install my "/sdfuse" folder with the images? I used a Ubuntu machine to create the bootable SD-Card so, the USB/SD-Card reader is working well, in other words, the problem is not hatdware but some software configurations of some sort.

EDIT following Chris Stratton comment about file system:
I have an SD Card containing the "/sdfuse" with the 4 image files (kernel.img etc) and a bunch of other file and folders. With Ubuntu Diskutility, I can see it as one partition W95 FAT32 (LBA) (0x0c) Master Boot Record. I can read/write just about anything on it from Ubuntu and MacOSX. The second SD-Card that I made is also seen has one FAT32 partition Master Boot Record, type W95 FAT32 (LBA) (0X0c) but I can't mount it neither from Ubuntu (but seen under /dev/sdb) nor MacOSX. That last one, is the one with u-boot on it. Just strange!  Just to work around the problem, I just had an idea so I can keep working, I just tried to boot with the "u-boot SD-Card" then, I changed the SD-Card "live" for the one with the 4 files. I used the command "sdfuse" to flash u-boot, kernel, android etc to my NANDFLASH device. Then, when I force a reboot from NAND, it boots into Android. It is OK for development but this is way too complicated for a production procedure.  Chris Stratton is probably right when he points to a filesystem partition or structure. I just did not figure it out yet. Anybody has some clues?

After running from Ubuntu Terminal "dmesg | tail", I get the following results:

```
 dmesg | tail
[5871490.553791] sd 16:0:0:0: [sdb] 7829504 512-byte logical blocks: (4.00 GB/3.73 GiB)
[5871490.556190] sd 16:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[5871490.556197] sd 16:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 03 00 00 00
[5871490.556201] sd 16:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[5871490.559054] sd 16:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[5871490.559064]  sdb: sdb1
[5871490.563912] sd 16:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[5871490.563920] sd 16:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[5872079.044194] FAT: bogus number of reserved sectors
[5872079.044201] VFS: Can't find a valid FAT filesystem on dev sdb1.
```

So, it appears there is something wrong with the format even though the card boots and is seen has a W95 FAT32 (LBA)(0x0c)

EDIT following the Comment from  [TheCodeArtist](https://stackoverflow.com/users/319204/thecodeartist)

Here is how I create a "u-boot" bootable image disk. I run a script (on my Ubuntu machine) that was created by Samsung. Here is what is inside the script:

```
#
# Copyright (C) 2010 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd.
#              http://www.samsung.com/
# 
# This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
# it under the terms of the GNU General Public License version 2 as
# published by the Free Software Foundation.
#
####################################
reader_type1="/dev/sdb"
reader_type2="/dev/mmcblk0"

if [ -z $1 ]
then
    echo "usage: ./sd_fusing.sh <SD Reader's device file>"
    exit 0
fi

if [ $1 = $reader_type1 ]
then 
    partition1="$11"
    partition2="$12"
    partition3="$13"
    partition4="$14"

elif [ $1 = $reader_type2 ]
then 
    partition1="$1p1"
    partition2="$1p2"
    partition3="$1p3"
    partition4="$1p4"

else
    echo "Unsupported SD reader"
    exit 0
fi

if [ -b $1 ]
then
    echo "$1 reader is identified."
else
    echo "$1 is NOT identified."
    exit 0
fi

####################################
# make partition
echo "make sd card partition"
echo "./sd_fdisk $1" 
./sd_fdisk $1 
dd iflag=dsync oflag=dsync if=sd_mbr.dat of=$1 
rm sd_mbr.dat

####################################
# format
umount $partition1 2> /dev/null
umount $partition2 2> /dev/null
umount $partition3 2> /dev/null
umount $partition4 2> /dev/null

echo "mkfs.vfat -F 32 $partition1"
mkfs.vfat -F 32 $partition1

#echo "mkfs.ext2 $partition2"
#mkfs.ext2 $partition2  

#echo "mkfs.ext2 $partition3"
#mkfs.ext2 $partition3  

#echo "mkfs.ext2 $partition4"
#mkfs.ext2 $partition4  

####################################
# mount 
#umount /media/sd 2> /dev/null
#mkdir -p /media/sd
#echo "mount -t vfat $partition1 /media/sd"
#mount -t vfat $partition1 /media/sd

####################################
#<BL1 fusing>
bl1_position=1
uboot_position=49

echo "BL1 fusing"
./mkbl1 ../u-boot.bin SD-bl1-8k.bin 8192
dd iflag=dsync oflag=dsync if=SD-bl1-8k.bin of=$1 seek=$bl1_position
rm SD-bl1-8k.bin

####################################
#<u-boot fusing>
echo "u-boot fusing"
dd iflag=dsync oflag=dsync if=../u-boot.bin of=$1 seek=$uboot_position

####################################
#<Message Display>
echo "U-boot image is fused successfully."
echo "Eject SD card and insert it again."
```

Also, you can see there is a call to a function "sd_fdisk".   I have the source code but it is also on Google code: [sd_fdisk.c](https://code.google.com/p/x210ii/source/browse/uboot/sd_fusing/sd_fdisk.c?r=e21cf135fa176ca05e92135b339d060a1af84eb6)

Comment: Wrong forum.  Try android.stackexchange.com

Comment: My chances to get an answer on the android forum are pretty low because being already a member of it, I can see that it is more dedicated to people using Android and writing Android apps. Here, I might I have a better change to get people with lower level sofware experience. People with Kernel, embedded linux, linux/android porting experience have good chance to know while Android users or Android application software people have less chance to know the answer.  That's why I chose this site.

Comment: @Simon, no, this would not be on topic at the Android site which concerns usage rather than development.  The present question barely touches on Android at all - it's really a fairly generic embedded question.

Comment: @Simon - No, it's not uniquely an android question, and it doesn't even involve a phone- or tablet- like device which consumer-device Android communities would be familiar with.  It is fundamentally an embedded-systems question, so please stop trying to dispose of it.

Comment: The problem likely lies in not having the right partition and/or filesystem structure on the card.  As a result, there is nothing that a desktop linux knows how to mount.  If you still had the original card unmodified, examining it would help.  If not, you will need to find out what type of filesystem the /sdfuse folder is supposed to be created on, create that type of filesystem either on the card volume or on a partition within it, and then copy the files in.

Comment: @ Simon, Chris Stratton is right. This u-boot would work about the same if my system had Linux or VxWorks has final OS. The real specific here comes probably more to the fact that I'm using an ARM Cortex A8 which requires a FAT SD-Card. Chris is also right about the filesystem. I will edit the question to give more info about it.

Comment: @ChrisStratton.  I'm not trying to dispose of it.  You assume too much.  Simply trying to offer the OP alternatives since I doubt he will find an answer here.  BTW, I frequent XDA Devs also and there are plenty of folks there who could probably assist.

Comment: Yes. It definitely looks like an issue with how the sdcard is formatted to copy u-boot into it. Can you list(or link to) the commands/steps that you followed to format and copy u-boot onto it?...

Comment: @TheCodeArtist. I added the info as an edit in the question.

Comment: Try the following cmds manually on a console. (Do replace sdX/sdX1 with the proper device like sdb/sdb1 or mmcblk0/mmcblk0p1.) ./sd_fdisk /dev/sdX; dd iflag=dsync oflag=dsync if=sd_mbr.dat of=/dev/sdX; mkfs.vfat -F 32 /dev/sdX1 Following this try to mount the newly created partition on you Ubuntu-PC. If it does NOT mount then the problem would be an incompatible mbr/geometry set by sd_fdisk and/or sd_mbr.dat. Comment out the above cmds in the script and format the sd-card(FAT32) using gparted. Next run the rest of the script i.e. fusing BL1 and u-boot.